# Java not processing JUnit jar

Tags: java, junit

I am unable to compile tests with JUnit. When I attempt to do so, I get this error:

```
package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
```

I get this error compiling the tests even if I put the .jar in the same directory and compile as follows:

```
javac -cp junit4-4.12.jar Tests.java
```

The contents of Test.java are:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Tests {

... several tests ...
```

It's not clear to me what the issue is, and as far as I can tell, it should work with the .jar -- it's the one from /usr/share/java, where it was installed when I installed junit.

Comment: wrong junit version.  I believe jupiter was introduced in junit v5.

Comment: What should I use instead on the version I have? Alternatively, where can I find the junit v5 jar?

Comment: Imagine a situation where you can travel backwards in time to 1925.  In 1925 the Blueberry programming language did not exist, thus your attempts to compile a Blueberry program will fail.  The Jupiter classes do not exist in junit 4 because junit 4 is 1925 and the Jupiter classes are the Blueberry programming language.  Try a google search for "maven junit 5" then download the junit 5 jar from maven central.

Answer (score 0):

As @DwB has already mentioned you have wrong junit version.

Here is what is jupiter in JUnit: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5
In simple words JUnit Jupiter API is a set of new classes which were written and introduced in junit 5 version only. And ur trying to use 4 version.

And also i want to clarify some points.

> even if I put the .jar in the same directory and compile as follows

It does not matter actually is your file in the same directory or not. Its all about it's path. If you are setting jar only by name of jar file (as you did) then your path becomes relative to your current directory from where u execute javac command. You can just use absolute path and run this command from every directory you want.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html (this one is for windows but for other os there are only minor changes in path writing)

If you get errors like package does not exist, classnotfound or anything similar then such kinds of errors almost always mean you have something wrong with your classpath or dependencies. In your case you simply had wrong version.

Now about finding necessary deps. In java world one of the main places for dependencies is maven central. Almost every opensource library can be found there and maven by default uses this repository to find and load dependencies (in your case these are jars) from there. Also you can use it to get necessary jars manually by simply using it's UI (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.0.0). There is download jar button.

Now if you know package or class but do not know in what dependency (jar for simplicity) it is located. In this case you can use http://grepcode.com or other resources which allow to search within available source code withit different repositories. In most cases this work. With juniper i did not manage to find smth there but in other cases this may help) Or the most simple case is just google package and in most cases it also will help to define entry point.

Now about solving ur issue. It seems that you will need as api as implentation. You will definitely need this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.0.0 but it seems that you will need juniper-engine too. First try adding only API and then just go on adding necessary libraries according to errors. You can add multiple jars to cp (read provided class path guide from oracle).